# Excel VBA: Array Inquiries

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am having trouble populating an array. I want it to contain values from another array that meet a particular requirement. However, the outputs are stored in the exact location in the new array as they are in the original array, and I want them to be stored in the first value of the new array and so forth. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let's see your code for how you decide which items from old array get populated in new array, and how you populate new array with those items.  Perhaps we can build from that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I assume you are looping in the old array and filling in the next array using the same positional number.

Try using a different one that one increments when the requirement is filled:

```
i = 1
j = 1
For i = 1 to ubound(first array)
    If condition then 
         secondArray(j) = firstarray(i)
         j = j + 1
    End if
Next
```

A little bit sloppy on the code, but I hope you get the idea!

Comment: Here it is, and yes. I was looping.

Comment: For n = LBound(endstock, 1) To UBound(endstock, 1)
    For m = LBound(endstock, 2) To UBound(endstock, 2)
        If endstock(n, m) < (0.6 * stock_cap) Or endstock(n, m) = (0.6 * stock_cap) Then
                orderlist = products(n, m)
        End If
    Next m
Next n

Comment: Your problem is that you are using the same number for the first array and the second. You need to use another one for the second and only increment when the condition is filled. instead of using n and m, use i and j, for example. And have them increment before [end if].